# Why nipples on a breastplate are useless?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a book and the sentence below showed up:

> "Like nipples on a breastplate."

After a research, the meaning intended was useless.

I would like to know why this sentence means "useless"?

Comment: Are nipples on a breastplate usefull?

Comment: What is useful inside a breastplate?

Comment: The breast it is protecting, one assumes, otherwise why wear one?

Comment: Likely a variant on "useless as tits on a boar" which is American slang going back to at least 1930: http://books.google.com/books?id=KbJZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22useless+as+tits+on+a%22&dq=%22useless+as+tits+on+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hr2kUaKBKYX28gSR2IDIBw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA

Comment: Eduardo, perhaps you need to look up the word "breastplate". Then, if you're still confused about how the simile works, consider asking a question on our [site for English language learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's nowhere near a standard expression, but it's a slightly sanitised version of AmE [tits on a boar](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22tits+on+a+boar%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and BrE [spare prick at a wedding](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22spare+prick+at+a+wedding%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: It's just one of a number of expressions that are a funny way to say that something (or someone!) has no use.  Besides @FumbleFingers additional examples, there is also, "As useful as *a horn on a plane*", "As useful as *an ashtray on a motorcycle*".

Comment: @Kristina: Quite. Such expressions have to be "funny" or they don't serve their purpose. But you have to know your audience when trying to explain *exactly* how useless something is. You can get away with [chocolate teapot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22chocolate+teapot%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) just about anywhere, but [a one-legged queer at an ass-kicking contest](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+one-legged+queer+at+an+ass-kicking+contest%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) needs a little more care.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the chocolate teapot isn't used much here (in US, in my age group, anyway) and the "one-legged..." is also new to me (and hilarious!) but one of my tried and true is "about as useful as a one-armed paper hanger" which is so TOTALLY un-PC! lol!

Comment: @Kristina: I quite like ["You're about as useful as a woollen colostomy bag!”"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22about+as+useful+as+a+woollen%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for that devastating additional "yuck factor" when you want to be really cutting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ewww!  Thank goodness lunchtime is over here.  That's a keeper!

Comment: @MattЭллен BTW is that last *ell* any useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bull, I am told, has little vestigial nipples that serve no purpose at all; hence the expression "as useless as tits on a bull."  "Like nipples on a breastplate" is likely equivalent to the former saying.  Nipples on a breastplate may serve an aesthetic purpose, but they add not a whit to the wearer's protection.

I encourage folks to invent "as useless as" sayings all their own.  Here's mine:

> As useless as lipstick on a gargoyle.

Comment: This answer is good for me ! Tks !